# Hiding windows shell from a program

Tags: batch, vb.net

I am running a batch file from vb.net, the problem is that everytime it runs a windows shell pops up and it is a bit annoying,how do fix this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477776/run-cmd-silently

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the `START` + `CMD` combination, passing the interpreter the name of batch file.
The important is to use the /B option of `START` command.